# React-native custom component renders list items under views of other components

Tags: react-native, view, react-native-flatlist, react-native-stylesheet

I have created an autocomplete textbox component which basically renders a list of suggestions as the user types. When it is the only component on the screen it works fine but when I try putting it inside a view with another component its view seems to render over the component it is placed alongside. When I put them in separate views the list seems to render under the view below it. I was just wondering if there was a way to render the list above the other views on the screen? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to render a modal on pressing the search view and the modal should contain your textbox for typing and the flatlist below it. The modal will render above all views on your screen. for more help read the documentation.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/modal